# Mocking with moq, trying to pass an object to constructor having multiple parameter

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am trying to mock a method that returns a IEnumerable set of data, like a list of all codes.

There is an Interface ISystemService.cs that contains this method, a service class called SystemService.cs that has the method definition.

System under test is:

```
 public static class CacheKeys
    {
      public const string ALLCURRENCYCODES = "CurrencyCodes";
    }
 public interface ICacheManager
    {
        T Get<T>(string key);
        void Set(string key, object data, int cacheTime);
        void Clear();
    }
public interface ISessionManager
{
}
public interface IApplicationSettings
    {
        string LoggerName { get; }
        int CacheTimeout { get; }
    }
public class EFDbContext : DbContext
    {
    public DbSet<CurrencyCode> CurrencyCodes { get; set; }
    }
public class CurrencyCode 
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public decimal CurrencyUnit { get; set; }
        public int? DecimalPlace { get; set; }
        public string BaseCurrencyCode { get; set; }
    }   
public interface ISystemService
    {
        IEnumerable<CurrencyCode> GetAllCurrencyCodes();
    }
//SystemService.cs
public class SystemService : ISystemService
    {

        private readonly EFDbContext db;
        private readonly ICacheManager cacheManager;
        private readonly ISessionManager sessionManager;
        private readonly IApplicationSettings appSettings;

        public SystemService(EFDbContext dbContext, ICacheManager cacheManager, ISessionManager sessionManager, IApplicationSettings appSettings)
        {
            db = dbContext;
            this.cacheManager = cacheManager;
            this.sessionManager = sessionManager;
            this.appSettings = appSettings;
        }
      public IEnumerable<CurrencyCode> GetAllCurrencyCodes()
        {
            var allCurrencyCodes = cacheManager.Get<IEnumerable<CurrencyCode>>(CacheKeys.ALLCURRENCYCODES);

            if (allCurrencyCodes == null)
            {
                allCurrencyCodes = db.CurrencyCodes.ToList();

                cacheManager.Set(CacheKeys.ALLCURRENCYCODES, allCurrencyCodes, appSettings.CacheTimeout);
            }

            return allCurrencyCodes;
        }
```

Test Method

```
[TestMethod]
        public void testCacheMiss()
        {
            List<CurrencyCode> currencycodes = new List<CurrencyCode>()
         {
            new CurrencyCode(){Id = 1, Code = "IND", Description = "India"},
            new CurrencyCode(){Id = 2, Code = "USA", Description = "UnitedStates"},
            new CurrencyCodes(){Id = 3, Code = "UAE", Description = "ArabEmirates"}
         };
            var mockEfContext = new Mock<EFDbContext>();
            var mockCacheManager = new Mock<ICacheManager>();
            var mockSessionManager = new Mock<ISessionManager>();
            var mockAppSettings = new Mock<IApplicationSettings>();

            // Setups for relevant methods of the above here, e.g. to test a cache miss
            mockEfContext.SetupGet(x => x.CurrencyCodes)
               .Returns(currencycodes); // Canned currencies
            mockCacheManager.Setup(x => x.Get<IEnumerable<CurrencyCode>>(It.IsAny<string>()))
               .Returns<IEnumerable<CurrencyCodes>>(null); // Cache miss

            // Act
            var service = new SystemService(mockEfContext.Object, mockCacheManager.Object,
               mockSessionManager.Object, mockAppSettings.Object);
            var codes = service.GetAllCodes();

            // Assert + Verify
            mockCacheManager.Verify(x => x.Get<IEnumerable<CurrencyCodes>>(
               It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once, "Must always check cache first");
            mockEfContext.VerifyGet(x => x.CurrencyCodes,
               Times.Once, "Because of the simulated cache miss, must go to the Db");
            Assert.AreEqual(currencycodes.Count, codes.Count(), "Must return the codes as-is");
```

Since the defined constructor does not accept one parameter, how to pass the object as parameter? Please advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `CodeService` is under test, then you want to be mocking its dependencies, not the `CodeService` itself.

You'll need to provide `Mock`s for all of the dependencies of `CodeService` to the constructor, i.e.:

```
     var currencycodes = new List<SomeCodes>
     {
        new CurrencyCodes(){Id = 1, Code = "IND", Description = "India"},
        new CurrencyCodes(){Id = 2, Code = "USA", Description = "UnitedStates"},
        new CurrencyCodes(){Id = 3, Code = "UAE", Description = "ArabEmirates"}
     };
     var mockEfContext = new Mock<EFDbContext>();
     var mockCacheManager = new Mock<ICacheManager>();
     var mockSessionManager = new Mock<ISessionManager>();
     var mockAppSettings = new Mock<IApplicationSettings>();

     // Setups for relevant methods of the above here, e.g. to test a cache miss
     mockEfContext.SetupGet(x => x.SomeCodes)
        .Returns(currencycodes); // Canned currencies
     mockCacheManager.Setup(x => x.Get<IEnumerable<SomeCodes>>(It.IsAny<string>()))
        .Returns<IEnumerable<SomeCodes>>(null); // Cache miss

     // Act
     var service = new CodeService(mockEfContext.Object, mockCacheManager.Object,
        mockSessionManager.Object, mockAppSettings.Object);
     var codes = service.GetAllCodes();

     // Assert + Verify
     mockCacheManager.Verify(x => x.Get<IEnumerable<SomeCodes>>(
        It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once, "Must always check cache first");
     mockEfContext.VerifyGet(x => x.SomeCodes,
        Times.Once, "Because of the simulated cache miss, must go to the Db");
     Assert.AreEqual(currencycodes.Count, codes.Count(), "Must return the codes as-is");
```

**Edit** If you however mean that the next layer up of your code is under test, the principal is the same:

```
var mockCodeService = new Mock<ICodeService>();
mockCodeService.Setup(x => x.GetAllCodes())
    .Returns(currencycodes); // Now we don't care whether this is from cache or db 

var higherLevelClassUsingCodeService = new SomeClass(mockCodeService.Object);
higherLevelClassUsingCodeService.DoSomething();

mockCodeService.Verify(x => x.GetAllCodes(), Times.Once); // etc
```

**Edit 2**
I've fixed a couple of typos in the code, and assuming `CurrencyCodes` inherits `SomeCodes` and that your cache key is a string, and pushed it up onto a [Git Gist here](https://gist.github.com/nonnb/9109213) with the corresponding cache miss unit test as well. (I've used NUnit, but it isn't really relevant here)

Comment: The method GetAllCodes() of CodeService.cs is under test. So i was trying to create an object for the class like var service = new CodeService(); and then Act on the method. Is that not correct?

Comment: You want to call the real `GetAllCodes()` method to test it, otherwise you are just testing the mock :). In this case, you want to ensure that `GetAllCodes()` utilizes and interacts with the cache and the EF Context correctly, as per above. It is the `Cache` and / or the `DbContext` which need to be returning your stub data. The above is for a cache miss, you'll also want to test a cache hit, viz  where the DbContext must NOT be called if the Cache doesn't return null. Once you've tested `CodeService`, you can then `Mock<ICodeService>` and test the next layer up of your code.

Comment: '1 mockEfContext.SetupGet(x => x.SomeCodes)
2      .Returns(currencycodes); 
3 mockCacheManager.Setup(x => x.Get<IEnumerable<SomeCode>>(It.IsAny<CacheKey>()).Returns(null);'

I am getting following error for above lines:
ln1: The best overloaded method match for 'Moq.Language.IReturnsGetter<Some.Data.EFDbContext,System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Some.Core.Domain.System.CurrencyCode>>.Returns(System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Some.Core.Domain.System.CurrencyCode>)' has some invalid arguments

ln2: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Some.Core.Domain.System.CurrencyCode>'

Comment: Thanks. Ya, i am getting to know Moq. Since i am new to this, its taking sometime to know it thoroughly. Please don't mind if keep posting questions. Appreciate your time.

Comment: I followed the approach from Gist Git but i am still not getting through it. **I have edited the code in the Question with proper typo and methods for better understanding**. Can you please help me with this a little further. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Although this discusses NMock, [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163904.aspx) has a good diagram (Expectations are the same as Verify, except they are setup before the test is run as opposed to afterwards).

Answer (score 1):

`allCodes` is your service.. its the mock you need to be working with. You shouldn't be creating a concrete instance of your `ICodeService`.. your mock exists to fill that role.

So, remove this:

```
var service = new CodeService(allCodes.object);
```

Your next line should be:

```
var code = allCodes.Object.GetAllCodes();
```

But then.. this test seems completely redundant after that.. since you appear to be testing your mock..

Also, `allCodes` should be called `serviceMock`.. as that makes more sense.

Comment: Thanks for you input. If the test becomes redundant, please suggest how i should proceed with the mocking the method.